# how can i access controller method value in postHandle in spring mvc 's interceptor

Tags: spring-mvc

```
@Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {       

}

@Controller
public ModeAndView createUser(User user){



}
```

how can get controller method createUser's parameter  ***user*** *value* 
    in interceptor 's postHandle ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could write an [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html). (or its convenience subclass [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html))

@See: [Spring Reference chapter: 15.4.1 Intercepting requests - the HandlerInterceptor interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)

It has the method:

```
void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response,
                Object handler,
                ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception;
```

This method is invoked after the controller is done and before the view is rendered. So you can use it, to add some properties to the ModelMap

**An example:**

```
public class VersionAddingHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    /**
     * The name under which the version is added to the model map.
     */
    public static final String VERSION_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME =
                "VersionAddingHandlerInterceptor_version";

    /**        
     *  it is my personal implmentation 
     *  I wanted to demonstrate something usefull
     */
    private VersionService versionService;

    public VersionAddingHandlerInterceptor(final VersionService versionService) {
        this.versionService = versionService;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler,
            final ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        if (modelAndView != null) {
            modelAndView.getModelMap().
                  addAttribute(VERSION_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
                               versionService.getVersion());
        }
    }
}
```

**webmvc-config.xml**

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="demo.VersionAddingHandlerInterceptor" autowire="constructor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: of course i know ,but i need the real value of the parameter of the controller method createUser, not to add some attribute to model,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly.

As you see in its parameters, an `Interceptor` has direct access to the request, the response and the `ModelAndView`. If you need to have access to the method parameter `user`, the simplest is to put it in model.

```
public ModeAndView createUser(User user){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addAttribute("user", user);
    ...
    return mav;
}
```

Then in interceptor `postHandle` method, you simply do

```
User user = (User) modelAndView.getAttribute("user");
```

Comment: o, this is need to  do some extra operations,